# SQL Server foreign key reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reference

```
CREATE TABLE users 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR (128),
    email VARCHAR (128),
    pass VARCHAR (128),
    paid BIT,
    rank FLOAT,
    status INT,
    active BIT
);

CREATE TABLE books 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (holder) REFERENCES users (id),
    name VARCHAR (128),
    author VARCHAR (128),
    year INTEGER,
    rank FLOAT,
    publisher VARCHAR (128)
);
```

Error list:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Foreign key 'owner' references invalid column 'owner' in referencing table 'books'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 18
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  `books` has no column named `owner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the columns to refer to them.  You can put the definitions all in one line like this:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    owner INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
    holder INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
    name VARCHAR(128),
    author VARCHAR(128),
    year INTEGER,
    rank FLOAT,
    publisher VARCHAR (128)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must declare var owner and holder
**SQL SCRIPT :**

```
CREATE TABLE books (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
ownder INTEGER,
holder INTEGER,
name VARCHAR (128),
author VARCHAR (128),
year INTEGER,
rank FLOAT,
publisher VARCHAR (128)
FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users (id),
FOREIGN KEY (holder) REFERENCES users (id),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR (128),
email VARCHAR (128),
pass VARCHAR (128),
paid BIT,
rank FLOAT,
status INT,
active BIT
);


CREATE TABLE books (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users (id),
FOREIGN KEY (holder) REFERENCES users (id),
owner INTEGER,
holder INTEGER,
name VARCHAR (128),
author VARCHAR (128),
year INTEGER,
rank FLOAT,
publisher VARCHAR (128)
);
```